Are these exposed beams structural?
If they are structural how difficult would it be to remove them and replace in attic?
Pics https://imgur.com/a/v3XLVdc Video: https://imgur.com/a/lmypLwh

wouldn't you expect them to be supported if they were structural?

Beams like those are almost always decorative.  Unless you have a post and beam home.

what's above them?. what is connected to them? are they hollow?

At first sight, the beams in the picture appear to be too small, span too long a distance, and are spaced too far apart to be structural. However, and as Huessman pointed out in the comments, the video shows that some of them are held by joist hangers, which would be odd if they were just decorative. Unless, of course, they were both decorative and not properly installed, and someone had to come after the fact and add the hangers. But that does not make a lot of sense.
The alternative to the joists being decorative is that they are something like 2x12s and you are only seeing the first 2" of their width, but I would argue that even so, the spans still seem to long, and the joists too far spaced to be structural. But who knows.
There is one sure way to tell: go up to the attic and look. You'll probably see a series of 2x10s joists 16" apart and furring strips holding the ceiling, indicating that the wood beams in the picture are decorative. Or maybe, albeit unlikely, that you have a post-and-beam house (as opposed to stick-built.)

The exposed hangers are a bit odd though.  You don't typically see those on decorative beams.  Unless they too are decorative, which is hard to tell from the media provided.

Here is a picture of the attic https://imgur.com/a/cP2cmk7

It's hard to tell. In the picture you can see joists running left-right. Those are perpendicular to the beams you see from below? also, there's a beam running up/down in the attic picture. Could be that what you are seeing from below is the bottom part of this beam.

In the attic there is a beam running across that’s has bolts spaced apart the same distance as the beams on the ceiling. https://imgur.com/a/OAy9YTQ
